# How to achieve split hero section view combining absolute/relative css with Tailwind and React

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, next.js, tailwind-css

I currently building a website using Nextjs, React, and TailwindCSS, and I want to achieve the Hero section UI like this website below.

[image]

What I want to achieve is:

- Left side with text title and some buttons
- Right side with some PNG image with `right-0`
- Dynamically change image size with a responsive aspect ratio

Currently, my image gets wider when the screen size increases, and can't control the size.
For example, when I set `max-w-4xl` in here like this, it can control the size but not keep staying on the `right-0`.

```
            <div tw="inset-y-0 right-0 pl-4 -mr-40 h-full pl-12 max-w-4xl"> <- specified max width here
                <Image src={PNGImage} tw="h-full w-auto" alt="Image" />
            </div>
```

Here is how I currently structured.

```
        <div tw="flex flex-row ml-16 relative overflow-hidden">
            <div tw="flex flex-col">
                <h1
                    tw="text-white-default font-bold text-2xl text-center"
                    className="whitespace-pre-wrap laptop:text-[48px]"
                >
                    Some title text...
                </h1>
            </div>

            <div tw="inset-y-0 right-0 pl-4 -mr-40 h-full pl-12">
                <Image src={PNGImage} tw="h-full w-auto" alt="Image" />
            </div>
        </div>
```

I think I have to add some `absolute` value to keep the responsive correctly but not sure how to achieve that.

Here are the example site I found with this structure.

https://www.abstract.com/

https://netbird.io/

Answer (score 0):

It can be done with both grid and flex. Choose whichever is easier for you to use. this is an example with grid.

```
<main className='grid grid-cols-12 h-screen w-screen'>
  <div className='col-span-12 lg:col-span-8'>
    <div className='h-2/4 relative'>
      <img src='/assets/icons/logo.svg' className='w-full h-full' />
    </div>
    <div className='flex flex-row space-x-4'>
      <button>test</button>
      <button>test</button>
    </div>
    <div className='flex flex-row space-x-4'>
      <p>logo</p>
      <p>logo</p>
      <p>logo</p>
      <p>logo</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div className='col-span-12 lg:col-span-4 bg-blue-500'>
      <p>Rest of the stuff here</p>
  </div>
</main>
```